# The big picture regarding products and coproducts in categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, intuition

I am new to category theory. I have been reading about products and coproducts in Chapter 0 of *Topology: A Categorical Approach* by Bradley, Bryson and Terilla.

Is it fair to say that products and coproducts are really just methods for putting two (or more) objects from a category together to create a new object within the same category?

I am trying to grasp the essence of what's going on before worrying about all the details (Cartesian product, direct product, direct sum, free product, disjoint union, etc.). I appreciate any help.

Comment: Essentially correct. But keep in mind (for now) that (co)products are not guaranteed to exist! Later on you will likely be working under the assumption that products etc. always exist, but it is not always the case.

Comment: @Trebor Thank you for your reply. Yes, now I see that the text mentions the category of fields does not have products, for example. Would it be fair to say that a (co)product in a category, if it exists, is whatever construction satisfies the diagram describing the relevant universal property? I don't understand enough to say much more, but I'm referring to those diagrams for which there is a unique morphism such that the diagram commutes. (See the Wikipedia pages on products and coproducts, for example).

Comment: Yes, that's always how universal properties work. As for your original question, it's a bit more subtle than that. There are other ways of putting together two objects in a category to form a new object (depending on the category), and the product and coproduct are two particularly distinguished ways of doing this satisfying particularly general and useful and important universal properties. It's good to work through the special case of posets, where they reproduce the meet and join.

Comment: This early in category theory it is actually a good idea to worry about all the details; coproduct and product are absurdly general constructions and the way to get a handle on them is to work through lots of examples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. One thing I'm learning is that there are at least two perspectives to take when learning math: 1) the high-level, big-picture perspective and 2) the detail-oriented perspective, that (for example) verifies every single statement in a proof. I have memories of doing a lot of 2) in the past, and not enough 1). I am trying to do more 1), but you are of course correct that working through examples is important to develop understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to think in terms of concrete examples to understand these notions. For example, the product of $X,Y$ in

- $\mathbf{Set}$ is the cartesian product $X \times Y$,
- $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ is the product of vector spaces $X \times Y$,
- $\mathbf{Grp}$ is the product of groups $X \times Y$,
- $\mathbf{Top}$ is the cartesian product $X \times Y$ with the product topology

and the coproduct of $X,Y$ in

- $\mathbf{Set}$ is the disjoint union $X \sqcup Y$,
- $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ is the direct sum of vector spaces $X \oplus Y$,
- $\mathbf{Top}$ is the disjoint union $X \sqcup Y$.

You should fill in the examples in posets as Qiaochu Yuan suggests, as this is again an instructive example.

In some sense, when you first think about products of objects, you should think of a construction that behaves similarly to the examples above - i.e. something like a cartesian product. A slightly more sophisticated viewpoint is that maps *into* products and maps *out of* coproducts are easy. This is a consequence of their universal properties.